# maximum number of registers allocated to fuction argument in c

Tags: c, function, compiler-optimization

I know that the C-compilers allocate some registers to the function arguments to enhance the access to the arguments inside the function and so making the code faster. But I am not sure about the number of these registers (different numbers I'v read/heard). 
 Is there 4 or 5 registers for this purpose? 
 Or is it maybe compiler/hardware dependent?
 Is there any reference about it?

Comment: It is hardware and ABI (application binary interface) dependent.

Comment: This is both compiler- and hardware dependent.  For code running on top of an OS, however, you can normally rely on compilers to emit code that follows the rules of the *Application Binary Interface* (ABI) specified by that OS for the particular architecture.  Google can help you find ABI documentation.

Comment: Also, an OS may support more than one ABI chosen on a per-process basis, and may support additional ABIs through emulation. For example x86_64 versions of Windows support 64-bit and 32-bit ABIs and older versions of Windows also supported a 16-bit ABI through emulation.

Comment: You are kind of asking: how many legs does an animal have? This is far too broad as it completely depends on CPU.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is very generic as not all functions are the same (ex: a function compiled to run on windows on x86 versus a function compiled to run on Linux on ARM)

In short it depends on:

- hardware architecture - how many registers the processor have, etc.
- calling convention (ABI) - is there a standard that the compiler follows in calling a function? (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)
- how the function ends up in the binary code (ex: it can be inlined, then there will be no function)

Compilers can support multiple ABI, or have their own proprietary calling convention or specific optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on ABI which is hardware, implementation and partially OS depednant. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

For example:

> ARM (A32)
>
> The standard 32-bit ARM calling convention allocates the 15
>   general-purpose registers as:
>
> r14 is the link register. (The BL instruction, used in a subroutine call, stores the return address in this register).
>   r13 is the stack pointer. (The Push/Pop instructions in "Thumb" operating mode use this register only).
>   r12 is the Intra-Procedure-call scratch register.
>   r4 to r11: used to hold local variables.
>   r0 to r3: used to hold argument values passed to a subroutine, and also hold results returned from a subroutine.
>
> The 16th register, r15, is the program counter.
>
> If the type of value returned is too large to fit in r0 to r3, or
>   whose size cannot be determined statically at compile time, then the
>   caller must allocate space for that value at run time, and pass a
>   pointer to that space in r0.
>
> Subroutines must preserve the contents of r4 to r11 and the stack
>   pointer. (Perhaps by saving them to the stack in the function
>   prologue, then using them as scratch space, then restoring them from
>   the stack in the function epilogue). In particular, subroutines that
>   call other subroutines *must* save the return address in the link
>   register r14 to the stack before calling those other subroutines.
>   However, such subroutines do not need to return that value to r14—they
>   merely need to load that value into r15, the program counter, to
>   return.
>
> The ARM calling convention mandates using a full-descending stack.[14]
>
> This calling convention causes a "typical" ARM subroutine to
>
> In the prologue, push r4 to r11 to the stack, and push the return address in r14, to the stack. (This can be done with a single STM
>   instruction).
>   copy any passed arguments (in r0 to r3) to the local scratch registers (r4 to r11).
>   allocate other local variables to the remaining local scratch registers (r4 to r11).
>   do calculations and call other subroutines as necessary using BL, assuming r0 to r3, r12 and r14 will not be preserved.
>   put the result in r0
>   In the epilogue, pull r4 to r11 from the stack, and pull the return address to the program counter r15. (This can be done with a
>   single LDM instruction).